# How to put the same logic of different pug files into one place?

Tags: pug

I have three pug files: a.pug, b.pug and c.pug:

## a.pug:

```
block header
  style
    .
      body {...}
    if (option.a == 'yes')
      include a.css
    if (option.b == 'yes')
      include b.css
  #main-a
    p This is page A ....
```

## b.pug:

```
block header
  style
    .
      body {...}
    if (option.a == 'yes')
      include a.css
    if (option.b == 'yes')
      include b.css
  #main-b
    p This is page B ....
```

## c.pug:

```
block header
  style
    .
      body {...}
    if (option.a == 'yes')
      include a.css
    if (option.b == 'yes')
      include b.css
  #main-c
    p This is page C ....
```

They share the same logic under the `style` block:

```
    if (option.a == 'yes')
      include a.css
    if (option.b == 'yes')
      include b.css
```

Is there any way to make the logic in a specific file so I can include it from my three pug files later? Otherwise, if I need to modify the logic, like adding a new line like:

```
    if (option.c == 'yes')
      include c.css
```

I have to make changes to all three pug files.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Is there a shared parent template you're extending?

Comment: Not for now but I can let it be!

Comment: That would be an easy way to keep it in just one place

Comment: Can I use if logic in “include” subpug file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the logic in an external file. The variables can be processed from there as well.

a.pug, b.pug, c.pug, ...

```
block header
  include styles.pug
  #main-a
    p This is page ....
```

styles.pug

```
style.
  body {...}
  if (option.a == 'yes')
    include a.css
  if (option.b == 'yes')
    include b.css
```